# How to use Google Web Fonts in VueJS app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, google-fonts

I did find this plugin https://github.com/gabiseabra/google-fonts-webpack-plugin

Updated the babel.config.js that was generated with the starter kit:

```
const GoogleFontsPlugin = require('google-fonts-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app',
  ],
  plugins: [
    new GoogleFontsPlugin({
      fonts: [
        { family: 'Inconsolata' },
        { family: 'Oswald' },
      ],
      /* ...options */
    }),
  ],
};
```

Add the font to the `#app` class

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
#app {
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
#nav {
  padding: 30px;
  a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2c3e50;
    &.router-link-exact-active {
      color: #42b983;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

But font is still Arial:

[image]

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inconsolata?selection.family=Inconsolata

Comment: Just add the Google Fonts stylesheet to the main .html file you’re rendering to.

Comment: You can use `@import` statements with scss mode like bootstrap does (if you are using vue-loader and sass-loader libraries)

Comment: Like mentioned here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/use-google-font-into-my-project/12331/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out, I have to import it like so:

```
<style lang="scss">
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata|Oswald');
#app {
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
#nav {
  padding: 30px;
  a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2c3e50;
    &.router-link-exact-active {
      color: #42b983;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use webpack to configure Google Font for Vue JS.
Install google-fonts-webpack-plugin using npm or yarn as a dev dependency.
Create webpack.config.js file inside root folder. Then add this into it:

```
const GoogleFontsPlugin = require("google-fonts-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
    "entry": "index.js",
    /* ... */
    plugins: [
        new GoogleFontsPlugin({
            fonts: [
                { family: "Source Sans Pro" },
                { family: "Roboto", variants: [ "400", "700italic" ] }
            ]
        })
    ]
}
```